# ORMLite - return item w/ maximum ID (or value)

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite w/ Android. I want to grab the ID value of the object w/ the highest-valued ID.

I'd also like to generalize this to requesting a single object w/ max/min value for any arbitrary field. What is the best practice for doing this?

I realize I could execute a raw query, but is there any other way that jumps out at anyone? I'm imagining something similar to Predicates when executing FetchRequests in CoreData on iOS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your answer looks good @Ben but I thought I'd give some extra info for posterity:

1. You could use a `queryForFirst` if you know your `limit(1)` will return a single result.

   ```
   qBuilder.orderby("my_field_column_name", false);
   qBuilder.limit(1L);
   MyEntity maxEntity = myEntityDao.queryForFirst(qBuilder.prepare());
   ```
2. A raw query would also work.  It involves more objects and checking but will be cheaper if the table size is large since you don't need to do the ordering.

   ```
   qBuilder.selectRaw("MAX(my_field_column_name)");
   GenericRawResults<String[]> results =
       myEntityDao.queryRaw(qBuilder.prepareStatementString());
   String[] result = results.getResults().next();
   int max = Integer.parseInt(result[0]);
   ```

Obviously, if your column was a different type then you would get a different object out of `result[0]` that you would have to convert into the appropriate type depending on the object.

Comment: limit() is depricated. You should load the list and return the first element (if available, pls check before)

Comment: Limit is deprecated where @MartinVonMartinsgrün?  Certainly not in ORMLite.  Under the covers I don't think JDBC `setMaxRows(...)` which it uses is going away.  The idea that you would load the entire result list (of possibly 1000s of entries) just to get the first one is (uh) not recommended for sure.

Comment: @Grey you are right, i've missed an important aspect: limit(int maxRows) has been depricated with the reference to use limit(Long).

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, upon further review of the ORMLite documentation, it appears I want something like [this](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html):

```
QueryBuilder<MyEntity,ItsIdType> qBuilder = myEntityDao.queryBuilder();
qBuilder.orderby("my_field_column_name",false); // false for descending order
qBuilder.limit(1);
List<MyEntity> listOfOne = qBuilder.query();
```