# How do you query in SQLite for a row with the MOST RECENT date value?

Tags: android, date, ormlite

I have a Model that has a `Date` variable. I want to know how I can query my SQLite table with the most recent `Date`?

Comment: Of course firstly you should make sure first that you also save a "date_issued" or such when you insert. Then when you query, add a ORDER BY date_issued DESC

Comment: Whutt!!!! youre from TUP... ME too!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>SELECT max(DateColumnName) FROM TableName</del>

**Edit:** Didin't see the `ormlite` tag before check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8974289/992063) solution

Comment: There's really no "ormlite" way to do this huh?

Comment: Yes there is i didn't saw the ormlite tag sorry, i have updated the answer